# Device Orientation not removed after Closing Video Player

Tags: ios, swift, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation

[image]

This is what I am facing issue.
My whole app is in Portrait Mode When a video plays in full screen and user rotate the device its default behavior rotates to landscape mode on clicking the screen/video in full screen control.

While on back/close of video I am facing same orientation ideally it should auto rotate to Portrait mode.

Please help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in viewWillDisappear() , change orentation back to potrait , the way u are changing it landscape , make sure u are changing to landscape in viewWillAppear()

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the orientation back to portrait mode in `viewWillDisappear`.

```
UIDevice.current.setValue(Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue), forKey: "orientation")
```